Partially nice waveform on debugger pin
I am looking at the waveform on my SWDIO pin during programming and most edges look very nice, but some do not.
Is this likely to be problematic?
What are probable causes?


You don't provide details about circuitry. But I'm not sure if it helps. It might. But taking into account that many of these look fine and fast and taking into account that some of them look very much like an RC curve, I'm going to guess this is a software bug where your port pin is switched from an output to an input. Probably other code forces it back to an output later. Or other code forces it to an input and then back to an output. But I think you must have something going on where the I/O pin, for short periods, isn't an output but instead is an input pin. Only thing coming to mind.

The curves appear to be spaced apart by about the same time. So it could be that during a period of active communication the I/O pin is firmly set to an output. But that in between these periods (which may be a single command or a single word, etc) the I/O pin is placed into an input mode until the next cycle/command/word, etc. I've no clue what kind of libraries you are using or if you are writing your own code. But this really looks software to me with what little I have to go on.

I think you may have your answer!

The SWD is a bi-directional half-duplex communication bus, so both the host and target can take turns and send data to the other party.
The sharp fast rising (or falling) edges happen when either the debug host or debug target actively drives the pin to high (or low) state.
When neither end is driving the pin, like when there is no need to communicate, or there is a change of roles who drives the bus (i.e turnaround bit time), the pin is not pulled low or high by either device, the bus is weakly pulled up by a resistor, and due to some stray capacitance on the bus, it charges in a RC waveform.
As there are turnaround bits in the SWD protocol, it should be normal to see these slow edges happening, especially if they happen exactly when they are supposed to happen.
It's only problematic when they happen when they should not, but it would mean the communication is failing anyway so you would get an error.
